# Detaching an element from document flow after positioning it

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside a td element with overflow:hidden set to it (the td). I want the inner div to be positioned in the document flow, and then detached from it so that it is allowed to overflow a little. How do I achieve that using CSS?

The HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td id="projectDetails">
     <div class="edit">
      <a href="">Edit</a>
     </div>
     <span id="projectName">Project Name</span><br />
     Category 1, Category 2<br />
     <hr />
     <span class="descriptor">Event Date</span>: 22/12/10 12:30<br />
     <span class="descriptor">Event Location</span>: Technion, Haifa<br />
     <span class="descriptor">Supervisor</span>: <a href="">Yosi</a>
    </td>
    <td id="projectDescription">
     <div class="edit">
      <a href="">Edit</a>
     </div>
     <span class="descriptor">Description</span>: 
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
     dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
     Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

The CSS:

```
table{
 table-layout: fixed;
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
 width: 1008px;

}
td{
 border-width: 0px solid;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#projectName{
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #892345;
}
td#projectDetails{
 width: 350px;
 border-right: 1px solid;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Basically I want the "edit" div to be positioned at the top right of both td's, but in the projectDetails td to not be constrained by its overflow:hidden attribute.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the td from the document flow by using the position css attribute.  This allows you to move the div around.

```
#projectDescription {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px; 
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/Jzcer/)

but I'm not sure this is the best way to go about it.

A better way to go about it is to ditch the `table`, and do the layout using only divs and css, which would simplify your code, make it more readable, less confusing, and separate layout from content.   I can post a simplified example if you'd like.

Comment: I kinda have to use a table for this specific section because I need the layout to stretch both vertically and horizontally and due to time constraints I can't learn how to do this with javascript. Also, I want to detach the div, not the td. I basically want the div to be positioned at the top right of the projectDetails td but not be constrained by the td's overflow:hidden attribute (the rest of the content of the td does need to be constrained by it though).

Comment: in that case, the css above lets you take the td out of the normal document flow. you can try `position: absolute` as well.

Comment: Position:absolute is one way to do it but it's not very elegant. I'll use it as a last resort, but I wanted to see if there's a way to do the positioning itself in a less unrelated-to-the-document-layout way.

Comment: meh, you're using tables for layouts and yet worrying about an 'elegant' hack to get them to work.

Comment: Well, no point in making things even worse, is there? Anyway, I managed to find a way to get rid of the overflow:hidden attribute so I have no need for a solution anymore. Thanks for your time.